# Infinite do-while loop with input

Tags: c++, function, input, fflush

I am trying to make a Bank Manager Program. For some reason, it turns into an infinite loop when receiving the wrong input. Whenever I try to have an input of something like "Pizza", it constantly repeats the do-while loop that keeps on printing the same thing. I don't know what else I am able to try to fix my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void ShowBalance(double balance);

double Deposit();

double Withdraw(double balance);

int main() {
  double balance = 0;
  int choice = 0;

  do {
    std::cout << "******************\n";
    std::cout << "Enter Your Choice:\n";
    std::cout << "******************\n";
    std::cout << "(1).Show Balance\n";
    std::cout << "(2).Deposit Money\n";
    std::cout << "(3).Withdraw Money\n";
    std::cout << "(4).Exit\n";
    std::cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      ShowBalance(balance);
      break;
    case 2:
      balance += Deposit();
      ShowBalance(balance);
      break;
    case 3:
      balance -= Withdraw(balance);
      ShowBalance(balance);
      break;
    case 4:
      std::cout << "Thanks for visiting! ";
      break;
    default:
      std::cout << "INVALID INPUT\n";
    }

  } while (choice != 4);
}

void ShowBalance(double balance) {
  std::cout << "Balance:$" << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << balance
            << std::endl;
}

double Deposit() {
  double amount = 0;

  std::cout << "Deposit:$";
  std::cin >> amount;
  if (amount > 0) {
    return amount;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Invalid Deposit Amount\n";
    return 0;
  }
}

double Withdraw(double balance) {
  double amount = 0;
  std::cout << "Withdraw:$";
  std::cin >> amount;
  if (amount > balance) {
    std::cout << "Insufficent Funds\n";
    return 0;
  } else if (amount < 0) {
    std::cout << "Invalid Withdraw Amount\n";
    return 0;
  } else {
    return amount;
  }
}
```